# How to remove paired bluetooth device in Android studio?

Tags: java, android, bluetooth

This code is not working properly. I get the message Removed Successfully but the device is not removed.

```
BluetoothDevice device = ((MyAdapter) (listView.getAdapter())).getSelectedItem();
 Set<BluetoothDevice> pairedDevices = mBTAdapter.getBondedDevices();
                if (pairedDevices.size() > 0) {
                    for (BluetoothDevice devices : pairedDevices) {
                        try {
                            if (devices.getName().contains(device.getName())) {
                                Method m = devices.getClass()
                                        .getMethod("removeBond", (Class[]) null);
                                m.invoke(devices, (Object[]) null);
                                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Removed Successfully!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            }
                        } catch (Exception e) {e.printStackTrace();} } }
```